# Persistent connection of websocket into live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, sockets, websocket, opensuse

I have implement rachet websocket with codeigniter and it's working fine in localhost. This is a main server.php that we need to run from terminal / cmd

```
require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";

use Chat\Chat;

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat)), 2000);

$server->run();
```

I run this file from cmd with following command

```
D:\wamp\www\my_project\api\application\third_party\Realtime\bin server.php
```

This command start socket and now any user access my site through browser then they are connect with socket and I can sent message to him. When I close terminal / cmd then socket close automatic.

Now my development is done and I upload all source on "openSuse" server. So my question is how I run above server.php file on live server ? (for example amazon ec2 OpenSuse server). because server don't have terminal / cmd.

Also this should run persistent so any time any user access my site they are connect to server and I will send him message.

I try many way but it's not working any how.

Comment: Look here: http://socketo.me/docs/deploy

Comment: Thank you @AlokPatel i will implement it and try to fix my issue, i will comment here if any issue regarding your given link.

Comment: @AlokPatel can you please tell me how can i set above Persistent connection in localhost ? I am using wamp (Windows). I want to do it without run command in cmd and task schedular. Any way to set any config file ?

Comment: If you're developing it's better to use cmd. It would help you to see logs and debug.

Comment: @AlokPatel i refer your given document and follow steps. Plz see ans given below by me, i can not add long comment over here :)

Answer (score 0):

after installing haproxy i create confing file `haproxy.cfg` into `/etc` directory
In this file i have set

```
backend ws
    server  ws1 my_public_ip:2000

backend www
    timeout server  30s
    server  www1    my_public_ip:80
```

Here `port 2000` is `websocket` port and `port 80` is my apache port
I also try with `127.0.0.1` but it gives following error

`[ALERT] 293/101352 (2291) : Starting frontend public: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]`

After skip this error i create `supervisor.conf` file in `/etc/` directory and add rachet program as per your given link
Here in command i gave full path to server.php file

`command                 = bash -c "ulimit -n 10000; exec /usr/bin/php /srv/www/htdocs/ci_chat/application/third_party/Realtime/bin/server.php"`

But it gives me following error

`Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.`

My apache run on port 80
pgsql run on 5432
Now i can not understand which service need to shutdown.